# How to make event loop run task concurrently?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

I want to call two function concurrently in `asyncio`, I do it with `loop.create_task`, but I find that it is not concurrently actually.

Here is my code:

```
import asyncio


async def foo(v):
    print(f"start {v}")
    for i in range(5):
        print(f"work in {v}")
    print(f"done {v}")


def schedule_foo():
    print("out start 1")
    loop.create_task(foo(1))
    print("out start 2")
    loop.create_task(foo(2))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
schedule_foo()
loop.run_forever()
```

this will output:

```
out start 1
out start 2
start 1
work in 1
work in 1
work in 1
work in 1
work in 1
done 1
start 2
work in 2
work in 2
work in 2
work in 2
work in 2
done 2
```

As you can see the main loop is async, but sub task is actually sync.

My question is `how can I make the function run in concurrently actually`?

Comment: I don't think that is possible using asyncio, as asyncio is single threaded. You probably will have to use multiprocessing to be truly concurrent. Using threads will not be concurrent due to GIL.

Comment: Asyncio is concurrent but not parallel. It's based on cooperative multitasking where async functions yield to the event loop by awaiting something that suspends. Since your function never awaits anything, it doesn't cooperate.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `await`:

```
import asyncio

async def foo(v):
    print(f"start {v}")
    for i in range(5):
        print(f"work in {v}")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print(f"done {v}")


def schedule_foo():
    print("out start 1")
    loop.create_task(foo(1))
    print("out start 2")
    loop.create_task(foo(2))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
schedule_foo()
loop.run_forever()
```